# Error creating bean with name 'centralPagamentoPfController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service';

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, jboss, backend

Error creating bean with name 'centralPagamentoPfController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'centralPagamentoPfImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'simulaPagamentoEntryDTO'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'br.com.itau.internet.mobile.pagamento.model.dto.PagamentoPfSimulacaoRequest' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/central_pagamentos")
public class CentralPagamentoPfController extends SummerControllerBase{


    @Autowired
    private CentralPagamentoPfService service;


                //-------PAGAMENTO------------//
    @PostMapping(value = "/pagamento/simular")
    public Protocol simularPagamentoPf(@RequestBody EntryProtocol entryProtocol){

        return service.simularPagamento(entryProtocol, ACTION_SIMULAR_PAGAMENTO, OPKEY_SIMULAR_PAGAMENTO);
    }
```

...................................

```
public interface CentralPagamentoPfService {

    Protocol simularPagamento(final EntryProtocol entryProtocol, String action, String opkey);
}
```

.......................................

```
@Service
public class CentralPagamentoPfImpl implements CentralPagamentoPfService, EstatisticaFactory {


     @Autowired
    private PagamentoPfSimulacaoRequest simulaPagamentoEntryDTO;

     @Override
    public Protocol simularPagamento(EntryProtocol entryProtocol, String action, String opkey){

            PagamentoPfSimulacaoRequest entity = entryProtocol.getBodyAs(PagamentoPfSimulacaoRequest.class);


        //code

   }

}
```

........................

```
public class PagamentoPfSimulacaoRequest implements Serializable{


    @JsonProperty("canal_pagamento")
    private CanalPagamentoDto canalPagamento;


    @JsonProperty("codigo_terminal")
    private String codigoTerminal;

    // geter e setter
}
```

Comment: `PagamentoPfSimulacaoRequest` in your case is a `DTO` and is not a bean. So you should not `@Autowired` it in `CentralPagamentoPfImpl` service

Comment: PagamentoPfSimulacaoRequest Needs to have a spring component annotation such as @Service.  You have it set in CentralPagamentoPfImpl.

Comment: tks, 
that worked!!!